# Hidden characters added while converting from dos2unix

Tags: bash, shell, unix, dos2unix

Input file in comma separated .csv format:

```
25 Mbps^M
25 Mbps^M
25 Mbps^M
0 Mbps ^M
0 Mbps ^M
0 Mbps ^M
0 Mbps ^M
ash Back  ^M
ash Back  ^M
ash Back  ^M
```

while converting from dos2unix,
the spaces before ^M is getting converted to hidden characters.

Need to get rid of it the spaces so that on converting from dos2unix hidden characters are not present.

Tried using sed, tr but nothing worked

```
for filename in *.csv
    do
        echo "Converting $filename to UNIX format!!!!!\n \n"

        tr -d '\r' $filename > test_2
        #Converting file into Unix format and moving to input dir
        cp test_2 $filename
        dos2unix $filename > /input/$filename
    done
```

After convertion from dos2unix, file should not contain any hidden characters.

Comment: `dos2unix` deletes `\r`s. What do you mean hidden characters? Did you check what those characters are using a binary viewer like `bvi` or `od`?

Comment: I'm curious why exactly you want to get rid of the spaces. If the values are actually space separated the spaces introduce empty columns which may be important for later parsing. If not, the spaces are irrelevant for most text processing tools.

Comment: There are no commas here so this really cannot be CSV format. Can you show a hex dump of what you get (just a line or two) and what you would like to get instead?

Answer (score 1):

As [@Oguz Ismail](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10248678) said, [`dos2unix`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dos2unix) removes [CR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return) from the data; what you call "hidden characters" are what are commonly called "spaces" (usually made by pressing on the large bar at the bottom of your keyboard).

You can achieve what you want with GNU sed:

```sh
sed 's/[[:space:]]*$//g' -i *.csv
```

- `[[:space:]]`: Space characters: in the ‘C’ locale, this is tab, newline, vertical tab, form feed, **carriage return**, and space. <sup>[[reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions.html)]</sup>
- `-i`: specifies that files are to be edited in-place. <sup>[[reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Command_002dLine-Options.html)]</sup>

You do not have GNU sed:

```
for filename in *.csv
do
  sed 's/[[:space:]]*$//g' "$filename" > "${filename}.out"
  mv -f "${filename}.out" "${filename}"
done
```